# RDMA WRITE: ibv_wc.byte_len does not match what I try to write

Tags: infiniband, rdma, mellanox

I'm an Infiniband/RDMA newbie playing with RDMA on Mellanox Infiniband hardware. I used the source code [here](http://blog.zhaw.ch/icclab/infiniband-an-introduction-simple-ib-verbs-program-with-rdma-write/). The program runs pretty normal at first glance: The server writes some bytes to the client memory using RDMA_WRITE operation. However, I found later that the number of bytes transferred, which is indicated by the write completion structure(ibv_wc) does not match the amount of data I put in the ibv_send_wr structure. Here is the code for ibv_send_wr initialization in rdma_write():

```
ctx->sge_list.addr = (uintptr_t)ctx->buf;
ctx->sge_list.length = ctx->size; //which is 65536
ctx->sge_list.lkey = ctx->mr->lkey;
ctx->wr.wr.rdma.remote_addr = data->remote_connection->vaddr;
ctx->wr.wr_id = RDMA_WRID;
ctx->wr.sg_list = &ctx->sge_list;
ctx->wr_num_sge = 1;
ctx->wr.opcode = IBV_WR_RDMA_WRITE;
ctx->wr.send_flags = IBV_SEND_SIGNALED;
ctx->wr.next = NULL;
```

Then I read ibv_wc.byte_len after I get a write completion entry in the write completion queue. It shows random numbers: 32537, 32743, 32533. I assume the transfer is successful because ibv_wc.status is equal to IBV_WC_SUCCESS. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ibv_poll_cq()](http://www.rdmamojo.com/2013/02/15/ibv_poll_cq/) page at [RDMAMojo](http://www.rdmamojo.com) blog, the `byte_len` field is only valid for a small subset of operations, so it is left uninitialized in your case of an RDMA write operation on the send queue.

> **byte_len:** The number of bytes transferred. Relevant if the Receive Queue for
>   incoming Send or RDMA Write with immediate operations. This value
>   doesn't include the length of the immediate data, if such exists.
>   Relevant in the Send Queue for RDMA Read and Atomic operations.

Comment: Thank you Haggai! Now I just check if the return value is correct or not. It works perfectly for me.